# How conf VS Code for correct lib resolving when works with several venv?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

We use python 3.11, poetry and VS Code.

I have ~/workspace folder where store two services. Each service has own in-project poetry venv, and all service's specified modules doesn't correctly identified by VS Code.

How make correct linking?

[image]

Comment: If I create a solution with two workspaces, I am able to set a python interpreter for each workspaces. Is that not what you see?

Comment: @JonSG I doesn't understand you question, I have two venv in one workspace, I marked it on screenshot.

Comment: VSC only recognizes automatically virt envs that are in the root of the workspace, and only one of them is active for PyLance, what if you use **Multi Root Workspace**

Comment: Are you using the "add folder to workspace" option to have a multi-root-workspace view?

Comment: @rioV8 your hint applicable, and looks good, thanks for you expertise.

Answer (score 0):

VSCODE uses the currently opened folder as the Workspace, so although you have two projects, they are in the same Workspace. Select the interpreter and other settings are effective for the entire [Workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings).

You have to open these two project folders separately in vscode so that they can be two different Workspaces. Or try to use [Multi-root Workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces).

You can also add the following settings to *settings.json*, this will add additional import to Pylance.

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "input/lib/path/here",
    ],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "input/lib/path/here",
    ]
```

If ther no warning on the editor page, but an error is reported when the code is executed.
You also need to add imports using the `sys.path.append()` function in your code.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(object)
```